# openssl 1.1.1g genrsa command freeze

Tags: openssl, plc

[image]i have openssl ;
`~ # openssl version -a OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020 built on: Fri Jul  3 08:43:55 2020 UTC platform: linux-x86 options:  bn(64,32) rc4(int) des(long) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) compiler: arm-linux-gcc -fPIC  -Wall -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl" ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/lib/engines-1.1" Seeding source: os-specific` running on a plc machine, and after an update from 1.1.1b to g. The script used for the generation of certificates for the server does not run. The first openssl call in this script (openssl genrsa) freezes, what is more confusing is once the openssl.cnf and the script for generation is edited to work on windows machine, no problems can be detected the key as well as the crt are beeing generated.

[GDrive Link to attachement of the install certificate script as well as the openssl.cnf file used](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T6da0I21zinhbhUhRrdpbrOyiEsLlgTX?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Another useful way to identify the problem is to run the openssl commands preceeded with strace like so (strace openssl genrsa -out ... ).Using `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` it was clear that the randomness was not enough to generate a key, any operations in /media/mmcblk0p1 increased the available entropy to generate a key. We will be looking into RNG tools or maybe enough io operations at boot time to have an active entropy pool.